# How to configure tcp wrapper

Tags: ubuntu, tcp, ubuntu-12.04

I have a server with ip-address `192.168.0.1` and a client with ip-address `192.168.0.2` both of them are able to connect with each other.

Now the problem is I have configured TCP Wrapper on my server side and have appended the following line in it's `/etc/hosts.deny` file

```
sshd : 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0 \
 : twist /bin/echo "Access Denied!"
```

But when I try to ssh from the client machine with the ip-address `192.168.0.2` it gives the message:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remotehost
```

But why is it not showing the message I have configured it for? Please Help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that if you were to telnet to port 22 you would see the Access Denied message.

Since the message of "Access Denied" is not a valid SSH protocol handshake your ssh client generates a friendly error message on the stage where the connection failed, the ssh key exchange, which is the first stage of establishing an SSH connection.

Comment: Ya. I tried to telnet and it shows the message. Thanks. But how can I make it to show this message if I try to ssh from the client machine?

Comment: The SSH protocol allows you to send a banner message before authentication is allowed, configured from your sshd_config, which will be diplayed by ssh clients. But using hosts.deny you won't ever reach that stage, as you prevent the client from reaching sshd in the first place.

Comment: You could use a `DenyUsers *@192.168.0.*` in your sshd_config